# How to unload windows.eval() loaded and interpreted Javascript?

Tags: javascript, eval

Have a complex client-side template system where resources are loaded via XHR (as strings) and then injected into DOM.

For Javascript insertion up until now we were dynamically creating script tags and appending them to the DOM, not only for speed in modern browsers but also because this makes it possible to cleanup/remove the scripts once the template is not needed any more.

However - it seems that in older browsers and IE (even the latest 10 version) in particular window.eval() is a lot faster in evaluating code than just injecting it via new tags - like 10x as fast. Even IE-native execScript is a lot slower than eval.

I'd try optimizing it to use eval for performance gain in IE, however I don't see any way to reference or/and remove such evaluated Javascript afterwards. If anyone has any ideas on how to go about this - would appreciate it.

Comment: removing a script tag does not remove the javascript it contained from memory so you have a problem that doesn't exist

Comment: Is there an actually measurable performance increase from removing the dynamically created scripts? If so, is this something that can't be achieved by simply using object-based namespacing and taking advantage of most JS implementations' automatic garbage collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For Javascript insertion up until now we were dynamically creating script tags and appending them to the DOM, not only for speed in modern browsers but also because this makes it possible to cleanup/remove the scripts once the template is not needed any more.

I think you may be misunderstanding something there. Removing a `script` element does **not** remove the script it contained from the JavaScript context it was loaded into: http://jsbin.com/ujirat

> However - it seems that in older browsers and IE (even the latest 10 version) in particular window.eval() is a lot faster in evaluating code than just injecting it via new tags - like 10x as fast...however I don't see any way to reference or/and remove such evaluated Javascript afterwards.

It's exactly the same as script loaded via `script` tags: The only way to "unload" it is to remove all references to it, which makes it eligible for garbage collection. The best way to do that is to have your scripts define a **single**, global symbol that contains all of the functionality of that script, e.g.:

```
var foo = (function () {
    var f = {};

    f.foo = function() { ... };

    f.bar = function() { ... };

    return f;
})();
```

You can then "unload" that by doing:

```
foo = undefined;
```

...provided it doesn't give out references to itself that that doesn't clean up (such as setting up event handlers or other closures).

Comment: Going to accept your answer in a while ie. accept that its not possible to do. I was hoping for something more universal since not all of the JS libraries I'm loading are my own. And a lot of them do attach all kinds of events, etc. etc...

BTW good point about accepting answers - have rectified that.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, most libraries are designed to be loaded, but not unloaded. Getting them to unload can be non-trivial.

Comment: Whats frustrating about is that CSS doesn't work the same way for example. I can inject a custom style tag, fill it with CSS, then remove it - and it removes the interpreted styles from browser memory too...

Comment: @Michael: I know. Very handy that. But code is fundamentally different from a stylesheet.